# PNG Pixel Forces

Tags: code-golf

[image]

**Challenge**

A Pixel World is a PNG image where gravitational, electromagnetic, and nuclear forces no longer exist. Special forces known as "pixel forces" are all that remain. We define this force as

> F<sub>p->q</sub> = a * (p * q) / (r * r) * r̂

- `F` is the pixel force that `p` exerts on `q`
- `a` is Adams' constant, defined as  `a = 4.2 * 10 ^ 1`
- `p` and `q` are charges on two pixels
- `r` is the distance from `p` to `q`
- `r̂` is the direction of r in radians, measured counterclockwise* from the positive x-axis

<sub>*There are infinitely many acceptable values for any given direction. For example, 6.28, 0, -6.28, and -12.57 radians are all equivalent, and would all be accepted.</sub>

Three types of pixels exist:

- A red pixel holds a charge of positive one
- A black pixel holds a charge of negative one
- A white pixel holds a charge of zero

The bottom left pixel of pixel world is located at `(0, 0)`. The positive y axis falls up the page, and the positive x axis falls to the right. The total force on a pixel is simply the vector sum of all forces exerted upon that pixel. Like charges repel, and opposite charges attract.

Given a file path to a Pixel World, as well as two integers `x` and `y`, output the total force exerted on the pixel at location `(x, y)` in the format `<magnitude>\n<direction>`. Output must be accurate to at least 2 decimal places, but you may output more if you want. Direction must be output in radians. The integers `x` and `y` are guaranteed to be within the world boundary.

**Deliverables**

You must include a program, and a command that can be used to run your program. Two examples:

> python AbsolutelyPositive.py "C:\Pixtona.png" 50 40
> java UltimateAttraction "C:\Jupix.png" 30 30

**Example Image**

In the [image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoBIi.png), there is a black pixel at `(100, 104)`.

> Pixars.png
>
> [image]

**Example Output**

This output does *not* correspond to the above input.

> 534.19721014
> 4.32605416

**Need help getting started?**

I wrote some example code [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iMaakjmPhZu_Un4zGQRtKH7jNIrRLvkAX5-3H6igVKQ/edit?usp=sharing). I haven't tested it, so use it at your own risk.

Comment: Can it be PPM instead of PNG? and typically, images put 0,0 in top left corner, do we have to rotate it?

Comment: @user137 Everyone has to handle the PNG image format. I'm considering posting some Java code to get people started. I don't want to start adding optional requirements. The bottom left was selected as (0,0) because this allows us to use a right hand coordinate system and measure radians counterclockwise from the positive x-axis. If we place (0,0) in the top left, and radians would be measured clockwise from the positive x-axis. No matter which way you do it, some standard will unfortunately be broken. Couldn't you just flip the image anyway?

Comment: I love the intro picture...

Comment: I think the choice for PNG will really hold people back, except those with ready knowledge of Java — which, as far as I know, is the only language with something like ImageIO. C++, for one, doesn't have it.

Comment: Nice challenge. PNG is fine IMO. Btw, here are some questions I have while attempting it. 
       
1. I'm not sure if is it me, but I can't seem to find the black pixel in (99,101) in the image.    
    
2. Is the example output the answer for the test image?   

3. For the direction, if the angle is < pi degrees clockwise from the +ve x-axis, is negative values (i.e. 0 < Angle < pi) allowed, or must it be (pi < Angle < 2*pi) ?

Comment: @bitpwner Whoops, I was way off. The black pixel is at `(100, 104)`. Sorry about that! For reference, the coordinates in Microsoft Paint are `(100, 40)`. Paint indexes from a different corner, but it displays the coordinates of your cursor so I thought it might come in handy. I also checked the embedded image, and Stack Exchange did *not* resize it, so it is safe to use. As far as radians go, there are infinitely many correct outputs. For example, 2π, 0, and -2π are all equivalent outputs, as they all refer to the same angle. Negative values are fine.

Comment: Ah, just about to sleep when saw your comment. I guessed that you take one whole counter-clockwise round as 2π from the output and have adjusted my answer to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Python - 355

```python
import sys,Image,math as m
i=Image.open(sys.argv[1])
w,h=i.size
a=i.load()
X,Y=map(int,sys.argv[2:])
t=m.atan2
c=lambda i,j:2*(a[i,j][0]>200)-(a[i,j][1]>200)-1
p=c(X,h-1-Y)
V=H=0
for j in range(h):
 for i in range(w):q=c(i,h-1-j);y=Y-j;x=X-i;r=x*x+y*y;f=r and 42.*p*q/r;V+=m.cos(t(x,y))*f;H+=m.sin(t(x,y))*f
d=t(V,H)
print(V**2+H**2)**.5,[d,m.pi*2+d][d<0]
```

**Ungolfed**

```
import sys
import Image
import math as m

X,Y=map(int,sys.argv[2:]) # The X and Y coordinates of the test pixel

i=Image.open(sys.argv[1]) # Open the image
w,h=i.size # Get the width and height of the image
a=i.load() # Get a pixel access object of the image
V=0 # V = vector sum of Vertical Forces
H=0 # H = vector sum of Horizontal Forces

# Function to calculate the charge of the a pixel at x=i, y=j
def c(i,j):
    global a
    if a[i,j][0]>200: # If Red > 200
        if a[i,j][2]>200: # If Green > 200
            return 0 # We assume that pixel is White
        else:
            return 1 # We assume that pixel is Red
    return -1 # Else, we asusme that pixel is Black

p=c(X,h-1-Y) # Assign the charge of the test pixel to p

for j in range(h): # For every y value...
    for i in range(w): # For every x value...
        q=c(i,h-1-j) # Assign the charge of the current pixel to q
        y=Y-j # The y distance of the test pixel from the current pixel
        x=X-i # The x distance of the test pixel from the current pixel
        rSquared=x*x+y*y # The r-squared distance between the 2 pixels
        f=rSquared and 42.*p*q/rSquared # If rSquared is > 0, calculate the force. 
                                        # Otherwise, the force is zero
        V+=m.cos(m.atan2(x,y))*f # Add the Y component of the force to V
        H+=m.sin(m.atan2(x,y))*f # Add the X component of the force to H

d=m.atan2(V,H)
print(V**2+H**2)**.5,[d,m.pi*2+d][d<0]
```

**Some little program used to create tests:**

```
import Image
width  = 100 # Define your own image width
height = 100 # Define your own image height
image = Image.new("RGB", (width, height), "white")
pixels = image.load()
blacks = [(0,0), (1,1)] # Define your own black pixels
reds   = [(0,1), (1,0)] # Define your own red pixels
for x,y in blacks:
    pixels[x,height-1-y] = (0,0,0)
for x,y in reds:
    pixels[x,height-1-y] = (255,0,0)
image.save("y.png") # Save image
```

**Sample tests:**

[image]

```
Users-MacBook-Air:pngforces User$ python z3.py y.png 0 0
59.3969696197 0.785398163397
```

[image]

```
Users-MacBook-Air:pngforces User$ python z3.py y.png 50 50
0.0084 3.92699081699
```

[image]

```
Users-MacBook-Air:pngforces User$ python z3.py y.png 50 50
0.0084 0.785398163397
```

Just posting first... If there are any mistakes or issues, drop a comment down below, but will probably take quite some time to respond cuz I am really busy with other stuff.

Comment: I love the test program! It's a lot better than zooming in 400% on a little image, making dots by hand, then trying to record the locations of all the little dots. You must be a programmer!